# Unable to read a .any file within a tar file using apache-vfs-2.2

Tags: tar, any, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to read the contents of a .any file which is compressed in a tar file, using groovy script. It is using apache-vfs-2.2

```
Eg : /path/to/abcd.tar!/path/to/xyz.any
```

The error notified:

> org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not read from
>   "tar:file:///path/to/abcd.tar!/path/to/xyz.any"  because it is not a
>   file.

NOTE : Other file types like txt, pom, html, etc are possible. The issue exists with only .any files within the tar.

Could anyone have any suggestions here?